# Implementing Algorithms (Bubble Sort) to Organize an Array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

Today I was practicing writing a program that basically sorts the user's input from greatest to least value and displays the information after sorting. In order to do this, I have looked up some algorithms and came across the bubble sort method. After reading some articles I understand how it basically works, so I went ahead and reviewed some example coding for bubble sort algorithms, and implemented what I learned from the examples into my program. From the output I receive, it seems that the bubble sort method works... in a way. From what I can tell, the bubble sort algorithm/code that I wrote only seems to run through the array once, instead of running through the array until all integers are sorted into a greatest to least value list. Could someone help me review my code (especially the bubble sort section) and point me in the right direction?

Code below:

```
#include < iostream >

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int pancakes[10];
    int x;
    int valueSwitched;


    for (x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        cout << "Please input the number of pancakes person " << (x + 1) << " has eaten.\n";
        cin >> pancakes[x];
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
            if (pancakes[x] > pancakes[x + 1]) {
                int valueSwitched = pancakes[x];
                pancakes[x] = pancakes[x + 1];
                pancakes[x + 1] = valueSwitched;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "\n-----ListSorted-----\n\n";

    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        cout << "Person " << (x + 1) << " ate: " << pancakes[x] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I dont know bubble sort by heart, but it looks suspicious that you have a loop `for (int y=0;y<9;y++){` but `y` isnt used inside the body of the loop

Answer (score 1):

Your sorting code does just the same thing as

```
for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
    if (pancakes[x] > pancakes[x + 1]) {
        int valueSwitched = pancakes[x];
        pancakes[x] = pancakes[x + 1];
        pancakes[x + 1] = valueSwitched;
    }
}
```

taking 9 times longer.

You will have to exchange the loops of `x` and `y`.

```
for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
    {
        if (pancakes[x] > pancakes[x + 1])
        {
            int valueSwitched = pancakes[x];
            pancakes[x] = pancakes[x + 1];
            pancakes[x + 1] = valueSwitched;
        }
    }
}
```

Or to do it more efficiently, try this:

```
for (int y = 9; y > 0; y--)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < y; x++)
    {
        if (pancakes[x] > pancakes[x + 1])
        {
            int valueSwitched = pancakes[x];
            pancakes[x] = pancakes[x + 1];
            pancakes[x + 1] = valueSwitched;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's ok and probably answers the question, but reading the program the OP posted it seems to me that you should sort an array of pairs (person,pancakes) to keep track of which person eat a given number of pancakes.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a problem just in `sorting` the numbers. So you need to learn `bubble sort` first. I have changed a little in your code. Just see as follows:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 9-x; y++) {// changes
            if (pancakes[y] > pancakes[y + 1]) {//changes
                int valueSwitched = pancakes[y];
                pancakes[y] = pancakes[y + 1];
                pancakes[y + 1] = valueSwitched;
            }
        }
    }
```

now give the inputs `9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0` and it works..

Answer (score 0):

In the inner loop of the loops you are comparing and swapping `pancakes[x]` and `pancakes[x + 1]` instead of to compare and swap `pancakes[y]` and pancakes[y + 1].

```
for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
        if (pancakes[x] > pancakes[x + 1]) {
            int valueSwitched = pancakes[x];
            pancakes[x] = pancakes[x + 1];
            pancakes[x + 1] = valueSwitched;
        }
    }
}
```

I think it is just a typo.

Nevertheless I'd like to point out that it is not a good idea to use magic 
numbers like 9. Also there is a tradition to use names i, j, k, l, m, and n as indices.

As for the algorithm itself then it could be stopped when the array is already sorted.

Take into account that you could use standard function `std::swap` to swap the elements of the array.

I will show such an approach when the loops stop iterate when the array is already sorted

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    int pancakes[N];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
    {
        std::cout << "Please input the number of pancakes person " << i + 1 << " has eaten: ";
        std::cin >> pancakes[i];
    }

    size_t n = N;
    while ( !( n < 2 ) )
    {
        size_t last_sorted = 0;
        for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++) 
        {
            if ( pancakes[i-1] > pancakes[i] ) 
            {
                int valueSwitched = pancakes[i-1];
                pancakes[i-1] = pancakes[i];
                pancakes[i] = valueSwitched;
                last_sorted = i;
            }
        }

        n = last_sorted;
    }

    std::cout << "\n-----ListSorted-----\n\n";

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
    {
        std::cout << "Person " << i + 1 << " ate: " << pancakes[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter for example

```
10 1 9 2 8 3 7 4 6 5
```

then you will get

```
Please input the number of pancakes person 1 has eaten: 10
Please input the number of pancakes person 2 has eaten: 1
Please input the number of pancakes person 3 has eaten: 9
Please input the number of pancakes person 4 has eaten: 2
Please input the number of pancakes person 5 has eaten: 8
Please input the number of pancakes person 6 has eaten: 3
Please input the number of pancakes person 7 has eaten: 7
Please input the number of pancakes person 8 has eaten: 4
Please input the number of pancakes person 9 has eaten: 6
Please input the number of pancakes person 10 has eaten: 5

-----ListSorted-----

Person 1 ate: 1
Person 2 ate: 2
Person 3 ate: 3
Person 4 ate: 4
Person 5 ate: 5
Person 6 ate: 6
Person 7 ate: 7
Person 8 ate: 8
Person 9 ate: 9
Person 10 ate: 10
```

If you want to keep the relation between a person and eaten pancakes by the person then you should declare an array of pairs.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    std::pair<size_t, int> pancakes[N];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
    {
        std::cout << "Please input the number of pancakes person " << i + 1 << " has eaten.\n";
        pancakes[i].first = i + 1;
        std::cin >> pancakes[i].second;
    }

    size_t n = N;
    while ( !( n < 2 ) )
    {
        size_t last_sorted = 0;
        for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++) 
        {
            if ( pancakes[i-1].second > pancakes[i].second ) 
            {
                auto valueSwitched = pancakes[i-1];
                pancakes[i-1] = pancakes[i];
                pancakes[i] = valueSwitched;
                last_sorted = i;
            }
        }

        n = last_sorted;
    }

    std::cout << "\n-----ListSorted-----\n\n";

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
    {
        std::cout << "Person " << pancakes[i].first << " ate: " << pancakes[i].second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For the same input as above its sorted output will look like

```
-----ListSorted-----

Person 2 ate: 1
Person 4 ate: 2
Person 6 ate: 3
Person 8 ate: 4
Person 10 ate: 5
Person 9 ate: 6
Person 7 ate: 7
Person 5 ate: 8
Person 3 ate: 9
Person 1 ate: 10
```